# multiplicative sequences $b(n)$ such that $F(s)$ is meromorphic

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function

Is it possible to describe the set of sequences $a(n) = \mathcal{O}(1)$ such that $$\frac{F'}{F}(s) = \sum_{p^k} a(p^k) p^{-sk} \ln p \qquad (Re(s) > 1)$$
is the logarithmic derivative of a function meromorphic on the whole complex plane ?

The restriction that $\frac{F'}{F}$ is meromorphic with all its poles being of the form $\frac{\pm k}{s-\beta}$ seems to be strong enough for deducing something on $a(n)$ - if it helps assuming the (generalized) Riemann hypothesis.

---

If $F(s) = \frac{P(s)\prod_{k=1}^K L(n_k s-s_k,\pi_k)}{Q(s)\prod_{m=1}^M L(n_m s-s_m,\pi_m)}$, $L(s,\pi_.)$ are automorphic L-functions and $P(s),Q(s)$ are two entire Euler products, then $\frac{F'}{F}(s)$ fits the requirements. If $K,M \to \infty$ it should fit too assuming everything converges compactly. A part of the question is if you can find other classes of meromorphic Euler products ?

Comment: "$F$ is meromorphic" is supposed to be the simplest possible relaxation of ["$F$ has a functional equation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class)

Comment: Clarification: do you really mean fully multiplicative, or just "weakly" multiplicative? Even in the "fully" multiplicative case, there are many elementary, natural Euler products that do not have a meromorphic continuation: "Estermann phenomenon"... Clarify?

Comment: @paulgarrett I see it is not clear, I mean if you can find a general construction for $a(p^k)$ such that $\sum_{p^k} a(p^k) p^{-sk} \ln p$ is the logarithmic derivative of an Euler product $F(s) = \prod_p \sum_k b(k) p^{-sk}, Re(s) > 1$, whose analytic continuation is meromorphic (so any product/quotient of shifted L-function works, times a simples (entire or finite terms) Euler product, but I'd like to know if you can find some other and more illustrative examples, and ideally if you can find a constraint on $a$ and $F'/F$ poles)

Comment: If the question is about producing Euler products with meromorphic continuation, I think automorphic L-functions provide the bulk of them... And there does not seem to be any "more elementary" prescription for the $a(p^n)$'s for a cuspform for $GL_2$.

Comment: @paulgarrett let $A(x) = \sum_{p^k < x} a(p^k) \ln p = \sum_{n < x} a(n) \Lambda(n)$. My idea was trying something like $A(x) = \sum_{\beta} \pm \frac{x^{\beta}}{\beta}$ and the Riemann explicit formula gives $\Lambda(n) = 1 - \sum_{\rho} \frac{(n+1/2)^\rho-(n-1/2)^\rho}{\rho}$ so $A(x) = \sum_{n < x} a(n) -\sum_{\rho} \sum_{n < x} a(n)\frac{(n+1/2)^\rho-(n-1/2)^\rho}{\rho}$ using that $(n+1/2)^\rho-(n-1/2)^\rho$ looks like $n^{\rho -1}$ plus other terms I get $\sum_{\beta} \pm \frac{x^{\beta}}{\beta} \approx \sum_{n < x} a(n) -\sum_{\rho} \sum_{n < x} a(n) n^{\rho - 1}$

Comment: @paulgarrett what I understand is that the theory of automorphic L-functions is more about producing Euler products with meromorphic continuation and functional equation, so I wanted to know about relaxing the functional equation part

Comment: In my perception, the difficulty is the meromorphic continuation. For example, with $d(n)$ the number of divisors of $n$, $D(s)=\sum_n d(n)^3/n^s$ has a simple Euler product, but has a natural boundary. (This is the simplest example of "Estermann phenomenon".) But maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way. Dunno.

Comment: @paulgarrett sorry to be annoying, don't you think it is an interesting question ? I found this description of [Estermann's theorem](http://dossier.univ-st-etienne.fr/esdr9935/public/reportMatsumoto.pdf) for the case $b(p^k) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b(p^k) = 0$ for $k > K(p)$, but I'd like to know if something more general can be said (or conjectured)

Comment: To my perception, it seems far too difficult a question. Work of N. Kurokawa in the mid 1980s treated many more general natural-boundary situations. Maybe I am over-interpreting the difficulties...

Comment: @paulgarrett just to say it seems you are thinking only to natural boundaries, but there is also the case $F(s)$ has a non-meromorphic singularity (by choosing $b$ correctly you can approximate any increasing function with $\sum_{p < x} b(p)$, so you can put the singularity you'd like as the first singularity of the Euler product $\prod_p 1+b(p)p^{-s}$)

Comment: assuming $a_n$ is completely multiplicative, $F(s) = \sum_n a_n n^{-s}$, from what I wrote above I find $\frac{F'}{F}(s) \approx - F(s) + \sum_{\rho} F(s+1-\rho)$ ($\rho$ are all the zeros of $\zeta(s)$) that should be very much like the [Weil explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)#Weil.27s_explicit_formula)